# jquery - selecting class with specific data-attribute value

Tags: jquery

Having a bit of a dumb moment right now and can't figure out why this is not working.  It's been awhile since doing anything with jquery.

```
var owl = $('.owl-main');
var button = $('.owl-button');

owl.owlCarousel({
    dots:false,
    margin:15,
    nav:true,
    navText: [
        '<span class="o-page">Prev</span>',
        '<span class="o-page">Next</span>'
    ],
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        }
    },
    onChanged: callback
})

function callback(event) {
    console.log(event.item.index);
    console.log(button);

    button.removeClass('active');
    //$(".owl-button[data-id='"+event.item.index+"']").addClass('active');
    button.find("[data-id='" + event.item.index + "']").addClass('active');
}
```

My issue is `button.find("[data-id='" + event.item.index + "']").addClass('active');` does not add the 'active' class yet the commented out code above it, `$(".owl-button[data-id='"+event.item.index+"']").addClass('active');` works perfectly fine.

`button` and `event.item.index` are reporting correctly so why is that particular line doing nothing for me?

Comment: Can you show your Html too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `find()` .. You are using it the wrong way.. it will actually search for the child element within the button with the given attribute. But what you want is to find a button with the given attribute.

- The commented code is the way you have to do it.

**Edit:**  If you want to use the stored array of button itself to get this working then you can use **filter()** in place of `find`

Here is a reference http://api.jquery.com/filter/

`button.filter("[data-id='" + event.item.index + "']").addClass('active');`

Comment: So there is no way to use my stored ```var button = $('.owl-button');``` in that commented line that works?

Comment: Perfect - that is what I was looking for.  Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Glad I could help.